# Provide alt text in image with link, the link is in 2 different places in the same block content

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers, wcag2.0

I have an HTML structure like:

```
<div aria-label="User overview">
   <a ... href="profile_page.html"><img ... src="user_profile_image" /></a>
   Info about the user

   <a ... href="profile_page.html">User name</a>
   More Info about the user
</div>
```

Both links go to the same place. Should I add in the alt attribute the username, o this will be too repetitive for the screen reader users?

Should I remove the second link to the screen reader? If this one is a solution, how can I do that?

---

In the future I will change HTML structure, but for now on I have to keep it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the `aria-label` on the `div`. It's useless on an non-interactive element, or worst can cause accessibility damages.
2. [Images inside links](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/images/functional/#image-used-alone-as-a-linked-logo) must always contain an `alt` attribute when they are the only content within them

Once this is done, you may consider adding the `aria-hidden="true"` attribute to one of the links if you think those two links are repetitive. The other possibility is to use a javascript only solution for the click on the image which will avoid any keyboard related problematic. Because many people use keyboard navigation without using a screen reader.

You can also consider [combining the image and the link](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/2016/WD-WCAG20-TECHS-20160105/H2)